# src/app/reactive-form/reactive-form.component.html:47:48 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. src/app/reactive-form/reactive-form.component.ts

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray, form-control

## Object is possibly 'null'. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"controls"' can't be used to index type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.

Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.

```
<div class="form-group" formArrayName="skills">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of reactiveForm.get('skills')['controls']; let i = index;">
          <label for="Skills">Skills</label>
          <input type="text">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

## ts file

```
reactiveForm!: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reactiveForm = new FormGroup({
      // To set default value we need to pass this value instead of null.
      firstname: new FormControl(null, Validators.minLength(4)),
      lastname: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('patelchintan843@gmail.com', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      country: new FormControl('Canada'),
      gender: new FormControl('male'),
      hobbies: new FormControl(null),
      skills: new FormArray([
        new FormControl(null),
      ])
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.reactiveForm);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have the same question (with the solution) in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70329977/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-abstractcontrol-has-no-index?rq=2). Please, before ask a question try look for if there a similar question yet answered. (the SO it's the question suggested in "related question"

Answer (score 0):

in **ts** file write a getter for skills

```
get skills() {
  return this.reactiveForm.get('skills') as FormArray;
}
```

and in **HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" formArrayName="skills">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of skills.controls; let i = index;">
        <label for="Skills">Skills</label>
        <input type="text">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```